# Does a US immigration officer really have the power to deny entry to the country at personal will?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, officials, denial-of-entry

Quite some comments exist that in the end it is the individual immigration officer that has the final call to let you enter the US or not and that there is no way of objecting that decision.

Given the major effects of such a decision - you have a denied entry on record, complicating future visits - I find it hard to believe that a single person has the power to bring such much havoc to others. I can't believe you get denied entry because the immigration officer might have some domestic issue.

So is it an urban myth, or does entering a country remain some sort of lottery?

Comment: If it's a lottery, it's a lottery with good odds.

Comment: Note that generally speaking US politics and legal thinking often emphasizes the rights of citizens (or “US persons”, which includes permanent residents), as opposed to broader “human rights” so that a treatment that might seem (relatively) arbitrary or invasive is not necessarily seen as a problem as long as it is reserved for foreigners (cf. the whole “but we don't spy on US people” rhetoric as a response to the Snowden leaks).

Comment: @Relaxed: yes and no.  On a literal level you might have a point but most countries in the world tend to practice "my citizens deserve special protection all the time, and everyone else can fend for themselves".  Likewise, most citizens of those countries have no problem with the double standard.  You can see this in the world news all the time.

Comment: Is this specifically about the US or in general? If it's about the US you should change the title to read "*the* country".  "*a* country" suggests *any* country.

Comment: Also, this doesn't apply to U.S. citizens; U.S. citizens can never be denied entry to the U.S.

Comment: @Szabolcs See the edit history.

Comment: @DanS I am not sure. To continue the privacy example, I think that most countries seem OK with some level of hypocrisy but that's a little different. If it becomes a topic of discussion, you will see people pretend that it's not a problem or that it's justified, officials deny it or refuse to comment and go on doing something illegal, etc. but no matter on which side of the debate you are, nobody would think that “Don't worry, we just spy on foreigners” is a plausible justification.

Comment: I have always had this question about visa approval

Comment: note that they also have the power to grant entry - I have successfully entered the US on visa documents containing formal errors, for example, that would have justified denying entry.

Comment: It would of ocurse be interesting to back up all the "in principle, yes" answers with statistics: How often (e.g. per year) is entry denied at the border in spite of valid visa?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen those statistics would be muddied further by visa that are valid as issued but issued based on for example false information applied by the applicant or the applicant did things that would have led to denial of the application after the visa was issued.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Following is [the official text detailing powers of immigration officers](http://www.uscis.gov/iframe/ilink/docView/SLB/HTML/SLB/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-29/0-0-0-9505.html).

The key para within this is:

> (2) to arrest any alien who in his presence or view is entering or
>   attempting to enter the United States in violation of any law or
>   regulation made in pursuance of law regulating the admission,
>   exclusion, expulsion, or removal of aliens, or to arrest any alien in
>   the United States, if he has reason to believe that the alien so
>   arrested is in the United States in violation of any such law or
>   regulation and is likely to escape before a warrant can be obtained
>   for his arrest, but the alien arrested sh all be taken without
>   unnecessary delay for examination before an officer of the Service
>   having authority to examine aliens as to their right to enter or
>   remain in the United States

They have the powers to deny you entry but this again is tracked, recorded and in most situations the immigration officers are very vigilant not  to allow their personal beliefs and apprehensions dilute the facts of the case at hand. It is true that they might not be polite with you or behave in manner showing respect - but when it comes to denying entry - they would be very careful not to be seen as biased or prejudiced.

One has ability to [contact legal agencies and USCIS in case of apparent misconduct](http://www.uscis.gov/about-us/report-uscis-misconduct/report-uscis-employee-misconduct).

This would then become a fight which one can take it to a finish if one is committed enough. But yes as mentioned in the question here - there are chances of one being denied entry with no proper reasons which depends on the type of immigration officer one encounters

Comment: I'm afraid this answer is totally wrong.  I believe the quoted law ("(2)") has **absolutely nothing to do** with the powers asked about, in, the question here.  The quoted law relates to an additional, unrelated, power where in certain situations these officers can **arrest** people (ie, "put them in jail").  This has absolutely no connection to the ordinary function of these guys, which is, they can **turn you away at the border**.  The question here on this page is about being **turned away at the border**.  (Nothing to do with being arrested.)

Comment: @Fattie Your comment is basically right, but the answer isn't *totally* wrong.  An immigration officer at the border can and will arrest someone who is attempting to enter the country through some egregious violation of law, for example with a forged document, and the quoted law is the basis for that power.  But you are correct that the power to grant or deny entry arises from other provisions of law.

Comment: @Fattie The central premise of this answer is "this paragraph from a law holds the answer. It says this in plain English". Both parts of that are wrong -- it's about detainment, and while the rest of the text is correct on its own, it is in no way related to the first part of the answer.

Comment: Hi guys, regarding this 4 yr old QA which is suddenly attracting attention. (1) this answer is just utterly incorrect, indeed "utterly irrelevant" and should be deleted  (2) there's an odd phenomenon on SE sites - it happens even on the most technical of them as well like the programming sites - where an answer that is utterly incorrect (or indeed, as in this case, in the category "utterly no connection, to anything - at all") will for unknown reasons get a huge number of upvotes. I've often wondered what causes this "velocity voting", my guess is (cont...)

Comment: (... cont)  *if the answer is well-written in terms of grammat etc* there is a cohort of SE site readers who simply vote it up.  I am going to test this on some of the sites, by putting in answers that are utterly irrelevant (eg, question about yaks, I will put in answer about convection heating) but which are flawlessly formatted and "tick boxes" like having "references" and so on!  (ie, I'll just add totally irrelevant references, perfectly formatted, referred, etc).  I really think that's the mechanism!

Comment: Also, not that it matters, as well as the utterly irrelevant reference in pars 1/2/3, paragraph 4 here ("They have the powers..." etc) is astonishingly fatuous.  This answer is a great exemplar of an almost impossibly bad answer; it would be difficult to make-up a better example of a exceptionally bad answer.  (And again, with the totally mysterious "momentum voting" sometimes seen on SE sites.)  Perhaps it can be used as some sort of example of what not to do, or something.

Answer (score 39):

Yes, they have the power, but:

- it is all recorded, and somewhat appealable (you may not get in this time, but next time)
- an agent showing a pattern such as always denying fat people, or people of a certain religion, would risk discipline, there is supervision and management
- most of them are good decent people who believe they are protecting their country, and not just from "terror" or "job stealing" but from things like food diseases and pests.

All these jobs have qualifications to get them, and oversight. If you watch Border Security etc you will see agents going to their supervisors and laying out what they've found, for example. It is true that an agent having a bad day may feel that you're lying, and refuse you even if you're not. It's not true that this makes entering a country into a lottery.

Comment: `...always denying fat people..` - this is the worst kind :)

Comment: Especially since watching Border Security, most of the US customs officers I see are ... erm, how shall I put this politely ... slightly above their ideal BMI.

Comment: I can't say I'm particularly impressed with US border security.  They are paranoid and idiosyncratic, but at the same time I don't think they get much additional effectiveness for that. Once in line I overheard another traveler say "whenever I come back to my country [USA] I'm treated like a criminal" which is kind of how it feels.  Coming back from a trip to Iran the border agent kept insisting I didn't look like my passport picture.  I felt like telling him he was a moron but just waited for his pointless delusions to abate.  UK is almost as bad.

Answer (score 18):

The power to deny entry lies with just about every immigration official in every country, it is not unique to the USA.  Even with proper visas, the immigration official has the final say to allow or to deny your entry.

As others have pointed out, there are procedures to be followed before a denied entry occurs and most of the time there are avenues of recourse (such as having a supervisor included in the conversation or requesting a redress before your next trip).

I would hazard a guess that the number of people denied entry because the immigration officer was having a bad day or some other such nonsensical reason would be miniscule.  Most denied entries are based on a solid reason, inability to show financial support, improper documents, old offenses still lurking in the databases, aggressive attitude towards in immigration officer's questions, etc.

If you meet the requirements for entry, then you really have nothing to worry about.  If you are entering with borderline qualifications, then it can be a bit of a lottery.  If you are entering with improper documents, then it is a brick wall.

Comment: I guess it is matter of interpretation, but I would consider an officer following strict guidelines and rules when denying entry not a case where the individual have the power. In that case the power lies with the system.

Comment: Getting into semantics here.  Granted the "power" is vested in the "system", but that system authorizes the "individual" to make the decision to allow or deny entry while providing that individual with guidelines for making those decisions. So effectively the individual officer has the power to deny entry.

Comment: @andra the system lays out the rules to be followed, the individual decides whether to follow them and has final authority. Of course you can question that decision in which case another individual (usually a superior) will review that decision and make his own, again based on those same rules.

Answer (score 7):

Regardless of the rules, from personal experience I can say that in practice one individual officer can indeed arbitrarily block your entry when they are having a bad day.

---

A german friend of mine was accepted at a US university, and went to the Embassy in The Hague (Netherlands).

She had prepared all documents to apply for the visa and after having them reviewed, the officer (a woman who seemed to dominate the department) simply said No.

Upon asking what the problem was, perhaps whether any documents were missing she simply answered:

> I Just don't believe that you are going there to study

After this arguments did not help and my friend was left speechless.

She contacted the university, got a letter of recommendation from them and they helped her get a new appointment.

This time procedures made sure that her case was not handled by the same person. The officer helping her was less intimidating.

Whilst reviewing the documentation all seemed well, until the dominant woman appeared again, gave her a quick look and simply said No.

After this the guy handling the case looked very embarrassed, stopped examining the documents and rejected my friend. After the dominating woman left he whispered:

> I'm sorry but you shouldn't apply here again. Perhaps your school can make the visa for you

---

So, to conclude:
Even if you have all proper documentation, you can still get rejected without (what I would consider) a proper reason. I won't go into detail on how this impacted my friend but always make sure you have a plan B in place, and think twice before betting on being allowed into the US.

Comment: It's not quite the same situation, it's a visa application and not an entry refusal at the border. Furthermore, it's just not “any reason” but a well-grounded refusal, namely because the trip is deemed not be justified. Obviously, the agent's assessment might be unfair but the reason is clear. Similar provisions exist elsewhere and visas get refused, nothing new here.

Comment: @Relaxed: if there exists a means by which an official can refuse something, which is a purely personal opinion and need not be supported by evidence, then in practice that's the same thing as officials being able to refuse for no reason at all. Because they can always just put down this "magic" reason regardless of the real reason, and the lie could never be proved and probably never detected. Such situations are naturally corrupting, which is why it's important to detect them and apply appeal/review/oversight. I agree of course, that visa applications aren't the same thing as border entries.

Comment: @SteveJessop Indeed but then the real issue is that getting a visa is always contingent on a specific purpose and you don't always have any practical recourse against a visa decision. If you have some way to appeal the decision, then the courts can evaluate the reason and it very much makes a difference. On the other hand, if appeal is not possible or impractical, then whether the agent officially needs some evidence to support the reason given is just as irrelevant. (Also officials have to think of using the “magical” reason in the first place, which is ironically not always the case…)

Comment: @Relaxed: well, in this case it seems (and I find it a bit surprising) that you have an ad hoc means of "appeal", which is just to re-apply and hope for a different official. I wonder whether it would with hindsight have been a better move to re-apply through the US consulate in Düsseldorf, which is only 2-3 hours from The Hague. Maybe the consulates don't handle visas, so it would have had to be Berlin or Brussels?

Comment: @Dennis: "procedures made sure that her case was not handled by the same person" -- apparently procedures didn't make sure of that. They just made sure that the official *pretended* the case was handled by someone else, while in fact handling it herself again.

Comment: @SteveJessop I don't know about the US but often you cannot choose to apply where you want. Also, my previous comment was a bit abstract but it's in fact sometimes possible to appeal a visa decision (it's the case in the Schengen area for example). It's one of the reason why this answer does not really address the question, which is about decisions at the border where an effective appeal is virtually impossible.

Comment: I am not sure this German friend of your is telling you the whole truth. Maybe there was something wrong with her.

Comment: @QuoraFeans I'm sorry, but I don't like the attitude of your comment.  It's equally as likely that there was something wrong with the U.S. consular officer.

Comment: This is not relevant to the question at hand, which is about the officials at the border.

Answer (score 7):

This policy does exist, as has been previously mentioned.  It is important to understand that the reason this policy exists is to delegate the appropriate **authority** to act to the individuals who have the **sworn duty** to protect the country's borders. The policy is intended to give authority to the officers on the "front lines" of the border, interacting with the travelers.  It allows for situations where things just don't "feel right".

Consider the case from the incidents of September 11, 2001:

> [US Customs and Border Patrol Officer] Jose Melendez-Perez received applause from the commissioners and spectators as he described how on Aug. 4, 2001, **he refused to allow Mohamed al-Qahtani**, whom some commission members described as **the probable 20th Sept. 11 hijacker, to enter** through the Orlando airport **based almost entirely on a gut feeling the man was lying.**
>
> "I felt a bone-chilling, cold effect," he said. "He gave me the chills."

Credit: Baltimore Sun, [*Sept. 11 hijacker raised suspicions at border*](http://articles.baltimoresun.com/2004-01-27/news/0401270116_1_student-visa-hijackers-passports)

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned, for better or worse this is completely normal;

that is to say, every country operates in this way at the border.

(Indeed an interesting question is ... is there any country which is an exception to this?  i.e., is there a country you are "absolutely" allowed to enter, and the border officials literally cannot stop you (!) ... Is there such a country?!)

---

Regarding the USA case, I'm afraid I couldn't find the **actual document** explaining that an immigration border officer has this power. (Again it's hard to see how "they couldn't," but I couldn't find the relevant law or document.) Here however is the relevant assertion for one particular visa type:

https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visa-waiver-program.html

> "An approved ESTA (Electronic System for Travel Authorization) allows a citizen of a Visa Waiver Program participating country **to travel to** a U.S. port-of-entry (generally an airport) and request permission to enter the United States. An approved ESTA **does not guarantee** entry into the United States."

(emphases added)

Comment: Hi Wileke.  While all of the other answers are not incorrect (each thing said in the other answers is truthful) -- they really don't answer the question: they don't get to the heart of the matter.

Comment: Actually,  since (highly unusually for this site) nobody, whatsoever, has included a relevant reference, I'll try to sober up and paste one in.